# How to make distinct operation more quickly in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, distinct

There are 30,000,000 records in one collection.
when I use distinct command on this collection by java, it takes about 4 minutes, the result's count is about 40,000.
Is mongodb's distinct operation so inefficiency?
and how can I make it more efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is mongodb's distinct operation so inefficiency?

At 30m records? I would say 4 minutes is actually quite good, I think that's just as fast, maybe a little faster than SQL does it.

I would probably test this in other databases before saying it is inefficient.

However, one way of looking at performance is to see if the field is indexed first and if that index is in RAM or can be loaded without page thrashing. Distinct() can use an index so long as the field has an index.

> and how can I make it more efficient?

You could use a couple of methods:

- Incremental map reduce to distinct the main collection once every, say, 5 mins to a unique collection
- And Pre-aggregate the unique collection on save by saving to two collections, one detail and one unique

Those are the two most viable methods of getting around this performantly.

#### Edit

Distinct() is not outdated and if it fits your needs is actually more performant than $group since it can use an index.

Comment: ok,I will add an index on the field,and try again.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The [`.distinct()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) operation is an old one, as is [`.group()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/). In general these have been superseded by [.aggregate()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) which should be generally used in preference to these actions:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": { 
       "_id": "$field",
       "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }
)
```

Substituting `"$field"` with whatever field you wish to get a distinct count from. The `$` prefixes the field name to assign the value.

Look at the documentation and especially [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) for more information.